# Check-out is not available but “Pend a change to server workspace” is comming

Tags: tfs, tfsbuild

I am not able to see Check out Project  permission in any of the team projects under newly created project collection “ABC”. It is mandatory to have this permission for our projects, as we are using a combination of check out and check in permissions to enable branching option to the developers without check-in permission.

You may Check out permission is not commingling

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Whick version of TFS do you use?

Based on my test, in TFS 2015 and earlier version the item is "`Check out`", in TFS 2017 and later version the item is changed to “`Pend a change in a server workspace`”

It has the same limited behavior with "`Check out`".

eg:

When set the permission “`Pend a change in a server workspace`” to **Deny**, we cannot check out for edit. The error message will popup.

[image]

Comment: I am using TFS 2017 version.

Comment: @hasan Yes, It's by designed in TFS 2017 as I mentioned in above answer. It has the same behavior as "`Check out`"

Comment: Yes TFS 2017 they change the option.